# How to wipe the entire python3.x with all installed pip packages and pip on macOS

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, upgrade, python-3.8

After upgrading my system interpreter to python@3.8 with brew, now everything got out of order. I think brew had symlinks of `pip3` through `pip` which enabled the direct use of `pip install <package>` instead of using `pip3` after the upgrade, this thing stopped existing, whenever I call pip, I get a `bad interpreter: No such file or directory <python3.7 old directory>` and I wasn't able to install any new packages unless I refer to `pip3.8` by full path which is in `/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8`. So I symlinked `pip` to `pip3.8` which is not the best practice ever, and most packages depend on python3.7 are currently crashing ex: `jupyter notebook`, which when I start using `jupyter notebook` from the terminal, it opens jupyter in the browser, but as soon as I open a notebook, I get a kernel error because for some reason it depends on `python3.7` which is not there. Even when I tried `python3.8 -m jupyter notebook` I get the same error. Needless to mention most of the packages that are launched from the terminal ex: `scrapy` are looking for python3.7 interpreter. So I installed python@3.7 using brew which is automatically not installed in `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin` to avoid clashing with the system.

So ... you got the idea, I have a mess and as I do not understand the dynamics of how python structure lives within OSX system I was thinking the best way is wipe all `python3.x` including packages, pip and various components, break dependencies and let them depend on native `python2.7` maybe or I don't know I'm sure there is some clean way to do it and then do a clean install of `python3.8`. Any suggestions on how to do this without creating more mess and be able to clean everything up and do that clean `python3.8` install at the end?

Comment: Your "note" paragraph at the top will not help your question. Besides, the close vote is about "general computing hardware *and software*"; it's obvious the latter is intended here.

Comment: Depending on how many other Homebrew packages you have installed, it may be worth your while to complete nuke the `/usr/local` directory and reinstall Homebrew and your required packages. Just make sure anything in `/usr/local` is indeed Homebrew-installed.

Comment: I would not recommend letting packages depend on Python 2.7; you'll miss out on newer updates, since 2.7 gets less and less support from package developers.

Comment: And if that is "general" why do these tags exist? And btw i never said the paragraph is intended to help my question, the question is crystal clear, it's about communication which the other party lacks

Comment: If the paragraph doesn't clarify the question, remove it. If you want to ask for clarification about a close vote, do so in the comments. If you want to ask about why the tag exists, you can do so at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ . If you want to rant, this is simply not the place. As to why people flagged it as such: possibly because the question is about general software, in the sense of system administration. See also Edric's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using `which python` or `which python3.8` to be able to find where they are and remove em if that's what you want to do.

You can also try `alias python=python3.8` or whatever version you end up needing. To make it so you don't have to type that every time you open a new terminal, you can edit `~/.bashrc` and add it in there that way it's the default.

Comment: Thanks, i already symlinked pip but i'm looking for a more clean / system friendly way

Comment: You could use a python virtual environment `python3 -m venv venv` will create a folder `venv` which you can then "activate" with `source venv/bin/activate` then `pip3 install` whatever you want there. To "deactivate" just run `deactivate`